# How do I disable an HDD password?

Tags: laptop

I set up an HDD password on an Asus GW75 laptop, and I want to remove it. 
I don't see an option in the BIOS for this.

I have two hard drive bays and when I physically installed a new HDD it asked for the HDD password. When I enter it, it states "invalid".

With the original HDD only installed it will accept the password and boot up.

Answer (score 1):

Change the password and simply leave it blank ( press enter ).